# Effective way to convert 3D-numpy array to ASCII format

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, ascii

I need to make a conversion of 18 3D-numpy arrays (each weight~2 Gb) to the ASCII format files.
Here is the info about one of the ndarray:[image]

I've search in the web about any ideas of this convertation, one of them was to save ndarray to txt with `numpy.savetxt` but it seems that it works only for 2D arrays. For 3D arrays it was reccomended firstly to slice into 2D arrays and then transfer txt file into ASCII format file. But since I am new in Python I am not sure this is the optimal way to deal with huge massive of the data as I have. Becasue in my case it will be 256 2D-arrays for each file (and I have them 18 files in total).

Will be really appreciate for your ideas and help!

Comment: How do you intend to use this file?  Often it's easier to customize the write to suit the reader, than the other way around.  Readers that handle 2d csv are common.  I don't know of a standard for 3d.

Comment: For large arrays, you might consider HDF5 (using the [h5py package](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/)) or [compressed Numpy files](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html).

Comment: When you say ASCII file, do you mean you need to convert non-ASCII characters (e.g. non-basic Latin characters) to ASCII, or do you simply mean plain text files?  Given the arrays having a data type of `float32` I presume you mean the latter?  (i.e. ASCII isn’t the issue at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure can be done with the `awrite` function in Py4CatS or with `numpy.savetxt` function in Python.